Why doesn't the HttpResponseData work when inherited in response class?
I'm upgrading to .net 8 isolated model and I have a couple of http triggers that should write a message to a servicebus queue and send back a response message. I have created a response class where I inherit the HttpResponseData parameter. I can pass in values and when I make a call to the endpoint I get a 204 No content response.
When I remove the inheritance and add the HttpResponseData in the response class it works like a charm. In both cases the message is written to the servicebus queue.
I have tried multiple things but in as soon as a I add the HttpReponseData to the class as inherited I get 204.
This works:
public class TestResponse 
{
     public HttpResponseData HttpResponse { get;set; }
    
    [ServiceBusOutput(QueueName)]
    public string Output { get; set; }
}

This doesn't work:
public class TestResponse : OutputBase
{
     [ServiceBusOutput(QueueName)]
    public string Output { get; set; }
}

public class OutputBase
{
    public HttpResponseData HttpResponse { get;set; }
}

In both cases a message is written to the service bus queue.

Welcome! Please provide a [mcve]
